# Missing dependencies (numpy) when importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm following a Python tutorial where pandas is used and I'm running into a dependency issue that I can't figure out.

To install pandas, I ran:

```
pip install pandas
```

But when I open a python session and try to import pandas I get an error message saying "Missing required dependencies ('numpy')" despite the fact that I see it getting installed when I run the pip command to install pandas.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Full error message posted below:

```
PS C:\Python> python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Comment: do you have more than 1 python version installed???

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I think it may have been possibly related to having multiple versions.  I believe many months ago I may have installed the 64 bit version of python then proceeded to install a 32 bit version as well.  Either way, I uninstalled Python, then re-installed and tried the same process I had been using and it worked properly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try to install Anaconda 3 (it works on Windows and Linux), it contains all the useful libraries like panda, numpy... so you don't have to download or rebuild yourself

Comment: Although I fixed my issue as stated in the comment above, I'll be sure to check out Anaconda.  That's for the suggestion.